# Why the execution result does not meet expectations when inheriting an abstract class

Tags: java

```
class C {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        B test = new B(1);
    }
}

abstract class A {
    int i = 1;

    abstract void test();

    public A(){
        System.out.println("before test()");
        test();
        System.out.println("after test");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    int i = 1;
    @Override
    void test(){
        System.out.println("test()" + i);
    }
    public B(int i) {
        System.out.println("before test()");
        test();
        System.out.println("after test");
    }
}
```

When I run this code, the output is

```
before test()
test()0
after test
before test()
test()1
after test
```

I know the first set of output results comes from the construction method of A, and I don't know
why the variable i is 0 for the first time, but in second time is right.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating an instance of `B` using the constructor `B(int i)`.

That constructor starts by executing the super class constructor `public A()`. This constructor calls `test()`, which is overridden in the `B` class and prints the `i` variable of class `B`.

That variable is not yet initialized, since the constructor of the super class is executed before the instance variables of `B` are initialized. Therefore, it still contains the default value `0`.

After the constructor `public A()` is done, `B`'s instance variables are initialized (so `i` is initialized to `1`), and `B`'s constructor  body is executed. It calls `test()`, which now prints `1`.

Comment: Thank you, as I guessed, but I'm not sure